# unresolved external symbol inflateEnd (and others) while using boost Zlib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, zlib

I'm in the process of converting 32bit project to x64. In most cases it just means appending `64` to library paths (and eventually building those libraries for x64). Now I assume all libraries are already ready and the code is also `x64` compatible. But I keep getting errors for boost zlib library, like these:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateEnd
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflate
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateInit_
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflateEnd
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflate
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression"
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated"
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy"
```

I enabled verbose mode for linker (in MS Visual Studio you do this by adding `/VERBOSE:LIB` to additional linker options). Thanks to that, I can see this output line:

```
Searching .\..\..\libs\boost145\stage\lib64\libboost_zlib-vc100-mt-gd-1_45.lib
```

That would imply that the library was found in the `boost145\stage\lib64`. So what should I be looking for now?

One strange thing is that file that defines the first group of missing symbols (those that are not within `boost`) has header files within the project, `zlib.h` and `zconf.h`. Maybe this is some hint? The `zlib.h` defines external symbols as:

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT inflateEnd OF((z_streamp strm));
```

Obvious question is: where the hell is lib file for this header file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to resolve the errors I download the source from zlib and built the x64 dlls/libs locally.  There were a couple issues with solution file downloaded, fixes are described below.

Zlib 1.2.8 source code: http://zlib.net/zlib128.zip

Solution File for VS2012 is located at: zlib-1.2.8\contrib\vstudio\vc11\zlibvc.sln

Fixes:

1. Change: 
   `<Command>cd ..\..\..\contrib\masmx64
   bld_ml64.bat</Command>`

   to:
   `<Command>cd ..\..\contrib\masmx64
   bld_ml64.bat</Command>`
2. In zlibvc project properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Image Has Safe Exception Handlers -> set to No (/SAFESEH:NO). Info about SAFESEH: [Compiling libffi with VS2012 fails with fatal error LNK1281: Unable to generate SAFESEH image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630069/compiling-libffi-with-vs2012-fails-with-fatal-error-lnk1281-unable-to-generate)